# C++ is there a way to resize a vector to specific character?

Tags: c++, vector

Basically I have a vector that contains bits of binary and I want to resize the vector to be only the length of the useful info. The length of the Vector Is very large since it is holding user input, And I could not find a way to make the vector's length dynamic to the length of the users input.

so the vectors contents would essentially be ~
1001101010100110010110100000000000000000000000000000000

is there a way to shrink the vector to:
10011010101001100101101

```
myVector.shrink_to_fit();
```

doesn't solve my problem because the vector is populated with null data.

```
//Included Libraries
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

                             // Var Declerations
string inputText;
std::vector<int> ba; //ba=binary array* originally was an array


void displayBinaryVector()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ba.size(); i=i+8)
    {
        cout << ba.at(i) << ba.at(i+1) << ba.at(i+2) << ba.at(i+3) << ba.at(i+4) << ba.at(i+5) << ba.at(i+6) << ba.at(i+7) << endl;
    }
}

//Main Function
int main()
{

    // Gets input
    cout << "Please Enter What You Would Like To Be Encoded" << endl;
    getline(cin, inputText);
    ba.resize((128*8));
    convertToBinary();
    displayBinaryVector();
    return 0;
}
```

** edit **  clarified code (I think) and updated to my current solution.

I Think I have found A solution that works for my particular situation:

```
void displayBinaryVector()
{
for (int i = 0; i < ba.size();)
{
    cout << ba.at(i) << ba.at(i+1) << ba.at(i+2) << ba.at(i+3) << ba.at(i+4)     << ba.at(i+5) << ba.at(i+6) << ba.at(i+7) << endl;
    i = i + 8;
    if ((ba.at(i) + ba.at(i + 1) + ba.at(i + 2) + ba.at(i + 3) + ba.at(i +   4) + ba.at(i + 5) + ba.at(i + 6) + ba.at(i + 7)) == 0)
    {
        ba.resize(i);
    }
}
}
```

I am still curious if there is a method or pre-written function that you can call that would essentially be reversing the vector searching until specified value/values are found and deleting any elements that have been 'checked'.

Comment: Is the binary represented as integers, or characters or a bitset?

Comment: _if you are interested or if its required_ Neither. You should [edit] your question to contain a **[mcve]**, not your entire code. The code should appear in your question so that viewers don't need to browse to an external site (whose link may go dead)

Comment: Find the last `1` and then use `resize(int)`?

Comment: It seems that the required length of your vector `ba` is in the variable `binary1`...  `ba.resize(binary1)`.

Comment: I have a feeling that your code is unnecessarily complicated. If you are trying to do binary conversions, I suggest the use of `std::bitset`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it is represented as integers

Comment: @Tas sorry about the format errors this is my first time posting to stack overflow. will be sure to follow that advice in future posts:)

Comment: @A.S.H It seems as though you would be correct. I will try that and post updated results.

Comment: @FlourecentGreen5 I tried using 'std::bitset' before and could not figure out how to get it to work proper.

Comment: @A.S.H **update** at first glance I thought you would be right but binary1 is just ending up equal to the full size of the vector, since the function is checking every value in the vector and then adding +1 to binary1 each time it does this.

Comment: @TylorThurston Still not clear: How exactly do you want to reize the vector? Do you want to remove the trailing zero bits (on the right-hand side)? Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

The following removes the right-most zero sequence from a `vector<bool>` (Also works for `vector<int>` with 0-1 values):

```
#include <algorithm>

vector<bool> ba {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0};
ba.resize(ba.rend() - std::find(ba.rbegin(), ba.rend(), 1));
```

Using backward iterators, we `find` from the end the rightmost occurrence of `1`. Then the vector is resized to the gap between the beginning and this found position. The solution is robust and applies for special cases of empty vectors and for vectors with pure zeros or ones.